# What does this IF statement mean

Tags: linux, bash

I have been trying to find online what these if statement mean. Below are a few.

```
if [ "${snums[k]}" != "NA" -a ! -f "${aliases[k]}.4dfp.img" ]; then
if [ -f "$dcmfile" -a -n "`cat $dcmfile`" ]; then
```

The `-a`  used in these two examples do not make senses to me.

Comment: A good reason you may not have seen `-a` or `-o` is that they have been declared "obsolescent" by POSIX. Script authors are strongly encouraged to use the shell's `&&` and `||` instead

Comment: Oh i see. I always thought -a was for checking to see if a file exists.

Answer (score 2):

`-a` is logical AND. If both the operands are true, then the condition becomes true otherwise false.

`-n` Checks if the given string operand size is non-zero; if it is nonzero length, then it returns true.

Comment: And `-f` checks if the following [word](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) is a regular file. Also, you can use `-s` to check if a file is not empty.